# Selenium Python find element by CLASS_NAME returns CSS_SELECTOR not found

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to click on this element in Selenium / Python:

```
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-x-circle"></svg>
```

My code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5,.25).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"bi bi-x-circle")))

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"bi bi-x-circle").click()
```

The error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".bi bi-x-circle"}
```

I can make this work by xpath, but I'm wondering why this says it can't find a css selector when I'm searching for a class. I'd rather deal with class names just because they're easier to read. The element itself is an X in the corner of a popup, if that matters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".bi.bi-x-circle"))).click()
#OR
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".bi.bi-x-circle").click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It then returns:
`
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"bi bi-x-circle"
`
It didn't append the period. This got me thinking- I deal with broken vendor API modules in my day job, and so I looked at: \Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py :

`
if by == By.ID:
by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
value = '[id="%s"]' % value
elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
value = ".%s" % value
elif by == By.NAME:
by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
value = '[name="%s"]' % value
`
Why is Selenium converting everything to CSS_SELECTOR under the hood?

Comment: PS sorry it's refusing my formatting in that comment - tagging @f.hoque

That bit of code comes from the find_element function

Comment: I just checked out the accompanying CSS- there is no ".bi bi-x-circle" class in the CSS, but there is ".bi-x-circle" so that transform that Selenium wants to do by prepending a period and treating it as a CSS selector doesn't work. 

Weird that the class name and the css don't line up.

Comment: .bi.bi-x-circle

Comment: You are missing another dot

Comment: In css selector, each class  value are separated by space but to select by css selector you have to inject dot for each class value instead of space

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying. Selenium converts CLASS_NAME to CSS_SELECTOR by prepending a period and changing the By argument.

But in the HTML,the class is 'class="bi bi-x-circle"', while the CSS class is ".bi-x-circle", so the prepend/change that Selenium does fails to run.

So that's why that works/breaks, but back to my original question of why CLASS_NAME doesn't work here, I guess this can be written off as poor front end development? I didn't write the website, and the UI/UX is atrocious, which is why I'm automating my interaction with it in the first place, lol.