# how to select an element in selenium with find element by class_name when it doesn't recognize the element

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

os.environ['PATH'] += r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.investopedia.com/auth/realms/investopedia/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=finance-simulator&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.investopedia.com%2Fsimulator%2Fportfolio&state=84830f95-2e14-4468-87b6-45325beadf2c&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=ffc0eff2-93bb-4c25-86f2-f0697898c85b')
browser.set_window_size(1500, 500)

browser.set_window_position(x=0, y=0)

username=browser.find_element(By.ID, "username")
username.send_keys("########")
password = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
password.send_keys('#######')
password.submit()




'''
#First code tried
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "pushly_popover-buttons-dismiss pushly-prompt-buttons-dismiss") ,
        
    )
)
'''
'''
#Second code tried
time.sleep(35)
popup = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "pushly_popover-buttons-dismiss pushly-prompt-buttons-dismiss")
'''
#Third code tried
time.sleep(35)
popup = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Dismiss']")
popup.click()
```

here are my errors

```
#First tried
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:188:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:400:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:292:16

#Second tried
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .pushly_popover-buttons-dismiss pushly-prompt-buttons-dismiss
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:188:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:400:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:292:16


#third tried
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[text()='Dismiss']
```

This is the html of the site
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv4vb.png)

The error code says that the element does not exists, but I have copy paste it and doubled checked it.
I've checked the docs and the code is good.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/
I found this post here but I can't seem to understand what I should do
[Selenium Python find element by CLASS_NAME returns CSS_SELECTOR not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848023/selenium-python-find-element-by-class-name-returns-css-selector-not-found)
So how can i select and click the dismiss button?

Comment: Which is that element `(By.CLASS_NAME, "pushly_popover-buttons-dismiss pushly-prompt-buttons-dismiss")`? Do you have demo creds for us to test our solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That notification doesn't seem to appear when using Chrome, however appears when using Firefox. The following code will correctly input user/passwd, click the login button, dismiss cookie button if it appears, then dismiss the pushly popup:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1500")
firefox_options.add_argument("--height=500")
# firefox_options.headless = True

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)

url = 'https://www.investopedia.com/auth/realms/investopedia/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=finance-simulator&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.investopedia.com%2Fsimulator%2Fportfolio&state=84830f95-2e14-4468-87b6-45325beadf2c&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=ffc0eff2-93bb-4c25-86f2-f0697898c85b'

browser.get(url) 

username =  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
passwd =  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")))
username.send_keys("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
passwd.send_keys("###########")
print('filled in the details')
t.sleep(3)

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login"))).click()
print('clicked the login button')

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
t.sleep(5)

pushly_stuff = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pushly_popover-buttons-dismiss pushly-prompt-buttons-dismiss']")))
pushly_stuff.click()
print('pushly stuffs dismissed')
```

Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Make sure your selenium package is up to date, as well as Firefox, and the corresponding geckodriver.

Comment: But why is your code working and not mine?